# How to add a bespoke social sharing message to a specific page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter

I've used services like 'Add This' for a while but now I need to add a couple of specific bits of functionality to an ecommerce order completion page. It's to work like Amazon's order thank you page where it allows you to post a message to Facebook saying something like 'I just bought a widget on Amazon'.

Equally I'm looking for the equivalent in Twitter.

I've added a bunch of OG tags and share buttons but can't get it to do what I need. From further reading it sounds like I might need to create a Facebook app of some sort and use FB ui to create the link to post to the user's wall. I was hoping to do this without getting tangled up in that level of permissions etc but maybe that's not possible any more?

This is being developed on asp.net C#, in case there's a library that I haven't found in my searching.

Can anyone familiar with this type of development point me in the right direction?

Comment: The message part of any post/share on Facebook has to be typed in by the user, your app is not allowed to specify it for them or even pre-fill it. You could of course try and create an Open Graph story, where “buy” is the action and your products are the objects – but that requires some more effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Twitter, the simplest way is to use [Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent).

For example, if you want to share the text

> I love http://example.com

URL encode the text to `I%20love%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com` and use the Twitter Web Intent URI.  E.g.

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I%20love%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

When the user clicks on that link (try it!) or is directed there by your service, they'll be prompted to share that text.

Comment: Thanks, this will be perfect for Twitter.